# How to sync fingerprint login across Windows 11 and Linux Mint 20

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, configuration, fingerprint

I am a novice and I am trying to sync my fingerprints across Windows 11 and Linux Mint on a dual boot Lenovo T480. GitHub suggests an edit to the "/etc/python-validity/dbus-service.yaml" file, which is read only. I have attempted to edit the file with text editor without success. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After some time I discovered an answer that works. To enable editing of a yaml file, it must be opened under root. To do this, right click on the etc/python-validity file and then click on "open as Root". This will allow you to edit the file under elevated privileges. Thanks for your patience and thank you Kusalananda who kindly added more appropriate tags. Have a great day.